# What is the meaning of this famous Groucho Marx joke? "One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I’ll never know."

Tags: sentence-meaning, ambiguity, jokes

Can anyone interpret the meaning of this quote:

> One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I’ll never know.

This famous Groucho Marx joke has many explanations given on the Internet, but I still don't get it. Can someone explain it to me in simple terms?

PS: I've spent a long time googling the meaning of this sentence. No luck so far.

Comment: The first sentence could be read two ways: "One morning I was wearing my pajamas, and I shot an elephant." or "One morning, an elephant was wearing my pajamas, and I shot that elephant". The most natural interpretation is the first one. The second is quite fantastic, yet from the next sentence we learn that the author had exactly this interpretation in mind. This is quite unexpected.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to parse these crazy sentences](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20331/3281). (Note: In case you wonder why I asked 7 questions in one, look at the date. ;-)

Comment: @CowperKettle, Is <elephant> supposed to share meaning with <python>?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The joke hinges on the phrase

> **in my pajamas**

In the first line is ambiguous, it can be read as

> One morning, **in my pajamas**

meaning you are in your pajamas, or

> an elephant **in my pajamas**

meaning the elephant is in your pajamas

Of course **an elephant would never wear your pajamas**, so the listener will naturally assume **you are wearing the pajamas**. However, the following line

> How he got into my pajamas I'll never know.

Confirms the fact that **the elephant was wearing the pajamas**, which in itself is a funny **visualisation**, but on top of that to **shoot an elephant wearing pajamas** has never been heard of before.

The joke is based on **misdirection**, where the listener thinks one thing, and the teller says another

A similar joke is

> When I was born, they threw away **the mold**.
>
> Well, some of it grew back...

Being a play on the word **mold**, meaning either a **form** or a furry **growth on dead things**.

Comment: Many jokes hinge on this idea: make a statement that the audience will naturally and logically interpret one way, and then indicate that you meant the words in a different way, that is perfectly valid grammatically, but unlikely or unexpected.

Comment: Take my wife... **please!**

Comment: Put another (stiffer) way, all humor hinges on confusion of meta-levels.

Comment: This explains it quite well, but it also helps to know who made this sentence famous: Groucho Marx. Groucho was a humorist and a master of puns, that is, making amusing statements because of the different ways words and phrases can be used. Another favorite of mine: _Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana,_ which is a "double-pun" of sorts, playing of the dual meanings of both _fly_ and _like_. At the risk of spawning a few dozen more ELL questions, I'll supply [this link](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/43244.Groucho_Marx) – now, enjoy the master of bending English!

Comment: The first line is not ambiguous when the listener first hears it. If this were not the case, the joke wouldn't work. The listener only realizes its inherent ambiguity *after* hearing the second line.

Comment: @peter I was thinking of quoting exactly that same joke, and then decided not to for the sake of brevity. Twisted minds think alike.

Comment: @GoDucks Well, the hearer does not PERCEIVE an ambiguity, because the "correct" interpretation is so obvious. Then upon hearing the second line they realize the ambiguity that they didn't see before.

Comment: @Jay +1 A **good friend** bails you out of jail, a **best friend** is sitting next to you

Comment: @stangdon I've never ***meta-level*** I didn't like

Comment: These are called 'garden path sentences'. i.e. the reader/listener is lead down the garden path by the obvious (but ultimately incorrect) parsing of the sentence.