# "The complex houses married and single soldiers and their families"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Taken from Quora.com...

This sentence, among many others, plays on our association of parts of speech when we read the sentence:
**"The complex houses married and single soldiers and their families."**

**"Complex"** is the noun as well as the main subject of the sentence. The sentence is about the complex. The first interpretation of **"houses"** is almost always as a noun, but here it is a verb, which means **"accommodates"**. It is the same case with **"married"** which usually acts as a verb, is an adjective to the **soldiers**, which surprisingly comes after another adjective **"single"**.

To sum it up, the sentence is trying to describe a complex (an apartment complex, perhaps) where both single as well as married soldiers and their families reside.

**My question is:** Is there a name for such sentences?

```
P.S. I would really enjoy reading a few more of the kind.
```

Comment: Once on an April Fools' day, I asked this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20304/how-to-parse-these-crazy-sentences. The term is "garden path". (I'm not sure; we can regard this question as a duplicate, perhaps?)

Comment: It should be pointed out that this "garden path" phenomenon occurs in reading. In spoken English, the intonation patterns and other prosodic features would make clear that "complex" is a noun, not an adjective,that "houses" is a verb not a noun, and that "married" is an adjective not a verb.

Comment: @TRomano I agree. That's why I said read and not listen to. Intonation makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. [Garden path sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) are sentences that are grammatically correct, but the first reading of them is likely to be nonsensical. The term comes from [leading someone down (or up) the garden path](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lead_someone_down_the_garden_path) which means to trick or mislead them.

Comment: Answers that consist solely of links are discouraged. See [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370).

Comment: @ColleenV,  I gave the answer to the question, and as a courtesy I provided a link to an article about it. What more would you have?

Comment: I thought the best way to explain would be by example - if I've really misrepresented your answer, feel free to roll it back.